# Create tar backup on USB fails

Tags: usb, backup, tar

A question please: when I use a Data Taveler 100G3 USB stick, capacaity 128 GB to make a backup of my home directory I get an error:

tar -czvf /media/dick/linux-bck/home-usb.gz /home/dick
gzip: stdout: **File too large**
tar: /media/dick/linux-bck/home-usb.gz: Slechts 8192 van 10240 bytes geschreven
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

On the USB the file home-usb.gz is created, 4.3 GB in size.

The largest file in home/dick is about 150 MB in size.

If I use a 1 TB external harddrive instead, no error, and a 19 GB tar file is created.

Any idea what this might be ?

File system USB: FAT, file system external harddrive 'msdos'. If I check the external harddrive on a Windows PC it tells me filesystem is NTFS.

Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 Bionic Beaver

Comment: What filesystem is on the USB stick?  FAT has a 4.3G max size limit for common setups.

Comment: @ubfan1 It looks like your comment is actually the answer. I suggest you make it one.

Answer (score 2):

Your USB stick probably uses the FAT filesystem, which has a maximum filesize of 4,294,967,295 bytes (4 GB – 1).  To store bigger files, you either need to break them up (using something like split), or reformat the USB with another filesystem, like ext4, which can have larger files.  A clean repartition might be best, tagging the recreated partition with the "linux file type 83, then format that with mke2fs or the tool of your choice.

Comment: I have formatted the USB-stick in NTFS format. Now tar creates a proper backup on the USB-stick. Thanks to all for their help !